# Powershell to search for files based on words / phrase but also Zip files and within zip files

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have this script...

Which looks at a given network location and then goes through all the folders / subfolders to search for specific words / phrases. Looking to modify to be able to do the same for ZIP files. Working in the same manner, report back any ZIP files which contain the words set out but also any files within the ZIP...

Any help?

```
"`n" 
write-Host "Search Running" -ForegroundColor Red
$filePath = "\\fileserver\mydepts\IT"
"`n" 

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*test*" -or $_.Name -like "*bingo*" -or $_.Name -like "*false*" -or $_.Name -like "*one two*" -or $_.Name -like "*england*") } | Select-Object Name,Directory,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime | Export-Csv "C:\scripts\searches\csv\results.csv" -notype

write-Host "------------END of Result--------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have .Net 4.5 installed you can use *System.IO.Compression.FileSystem* library to create a function which will open and traverse contents of your zip files

```
$searchTerms = @( "test","bingo","false","one two","england")
function openZip($zipFile){
    try{
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" ) | Out-Null;
        $zipContens = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile);  
        $zipContens.Entries | % {
            foreach($searchTerm in $searchTerms){
                if ($_.Name -imatch $searchTerm){
                    Write-Output ($_.Name + "," + $_.FullName + "," + $_.CompressedLength + "," + $_.LastWriteTime + "," + $_.Length);
                }
            }               
        }
    }
    catch{
        Write-Output ("There was an error:" + $_.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

You can then run something like this to obtain filename,full path within zip, compressed size etc.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path -$filePath *.zip -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %  {
    openZip $_.FullName  >> c:\path\to\report.csv
    }
```

Comment: Could I add that into my script above? I am still a PS noob! Looks good, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure thing, just amend _c:\path\to\report.csv_ to where you want the output.

Comment: happy to help, make sure you accept the answer if my solution worked for ya;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scan the contents of a zip file, since it is compressed and will just come out as garbage. You would have to unzip the file and then search through it.

Follow these instructions: http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-extract-zip-files-using-powershell/

Copy it down locally and then search for it there, then delete the copies, repeat.