# Best way to perform "Checking 10.000 Zip files if there is a .txt file inside, and if yes, then delete the zip file"?

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-3.0

I am searching for the best way to check around 10.000 .zip files which are not all in the same folder. I need to check if there is a text  (.txt) file inside, and if yes, than delete the .zip file.
I can build the whole script if I have the best way to fastly check the inside of the zip.

I found different ways to check, I am using Powershell 3.0 and I don't use any community extension.

best way i foud i[Get the inside of the zip](http://damashiuchi.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/get-child-items-in-a-zip-file-recursively-using-windows-powershell/)

any help is upvoted immedeatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find most of what you need here:

[Powershell to search for files based on words / phrase but also Zip files and within zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378521/powershell-to-search-for-files-based-on-words-phrase-but-also-zip-files-and-wi/21428092#21428092)

Requires .Net 4.5

Comment: helped me, done the script.