# Read a filename inside a zip file without extracting it in powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a `.zip` file `file.zip`. There are a lot of files inside this zip file and only one text file with extension `.txt`. I want to read the name of this text file. Is there any way to read the name without extracting the zip file in Powershell or in C#?

Comment: Have you done any code for this?

Comment: You can find an answer at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c

Comment: Yes i was able to read the file name by extracting zip.But i wan to read the name without extracting

Comment: HABJAN

i want to read it without using any third party library.Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Shell.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object for enumerating file names from a zip file:

```
$zip = 'C:\path\to\file.zip'

$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
$app.NameSpace($zip).Items() | ? { $_.Name -like '*.txt' } | select -Expand Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run something like this if you have .Net 4.5

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" );
$zipContens = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead("C:\path\file.zip");  
$zipContens.Entries | % {
   if ($_.Name -match "TheFileYouAreLookingFor.txt"){
       # found, your code block
   }
}
```

This question will help: 
[Powershell to search for files based on words / phrase but also Zip files and within zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378521/powershell-to-search-for-files-based-on-words-phrase-but-also-zip-files-and-wi/21428092#21428092)